# ¿Cómo puedo darle dos eventos OnClick a un mismo botón en Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, eventos, onclick

Me gustaría incorporar dos acciones dentro de un mismo ImageButton, lo que necesito es que al presionar una vez, se ejecute una acción, y al presionar de nuevo el mismo botón se ejecute a otra acción.
Ejemplo: tengo una animación y un botón "play/pause" con una imagen como "⏯" al presionar la primera vez la ImageView se mueve, al presionar de nuevo el boton la ImageView se pausa.

Ya tengo los métodos de play y pause, pero solo me funcionan por botones separados.

[image: mi ejemplo de botón "play/pause"]

```
public class Juego1Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageView imgmov;
private ImageButton play, pause, play_pause;

//Posición inicial de la imagen
private float startValue = -400f;
//Posición final
private float finishValue = 800f;
//Duración de la animación
private long duration = 2000;
private ObjectAnimator animator;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_juego1);

    imgmov = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_pony2);
    play = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_play_mov);
    pause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_pause_mov);
    play_pause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_playpause);
    
    animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imgmov, "translationX", startValue, finishValue);
    animator.setDuration(duration);
    animator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);

    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (animator.isPaused()) {
                animator.resume();
            } else {
                animator.start();
            }
        }
    });

    pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (animator.isRunning()) {
                animator.pause();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: hola que tal, podrias usar solo un ImageButton playPause, y en el onClick cambiar el icono usando los metodos de `animator`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías crear una flag que te indique si se requiere dar play o no.
Te recomiendo extraer las lógicas de play y pause para que no las tengas que repetir en los listener, es decir, crear métodos Play y Pause, y los mandarías a llamar dentro de onClick.

```
private boolean play = true;

...
    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Play();
        }
    });

    pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           Pause();
        }
    });

    pause_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            
            if (play){
               // Realizas la lógica de play
               Play();
           }
           else{
               // Realizas la lógica de pause
               Pause();
           } 
        }
    });
...

public void Play()
{
   if (animator.isPaused()) {
      animator.resume();
   } else {
      animator.start();
   }
   play = false;
}

public void Pause()
{
   if (animator.isRunning()) {
      animator.pause();
   }
   play = true;
}
```

Comment: Creo que deberia de ser `Clase.this.play` para poder acceder a una propiedad desde un callback.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias por tu aporte, me sirvió completamente. Pensé en todo menos en crear los dos métodos aparte y llamarlos desde el onclickListener (las simplezas por las que pasamos los principiantes). Gracias amigo